# xpath selenium automatic email python

Tags: python, email, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create an automatic email from gmail with bcc. I did a code with Python 2.7 to create an automatic email but without the bcc's. I don't know how to do it.

The problem is when I try to run the code. I extract the xpath code for bcc on my email and then I put it on the python code. When I did that, i receive this error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

#Cargar Chrome Driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Martin/Desktop/chromedriver')

#Cargar direccion a la que queremos acceder 
driver.get("https://www.google.com/gmail/")

#Usuario
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierId"]')
email.send_keys("usr")

#Next
l_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="identifierNext"]/content/span')
l_button.click()


time.sleep(1)

#Contraseña
passwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input')
passwd.send_keys("pass")

#Login
l_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="passwordNext"]/content/span')
l_button.click()


time.sleep(1)

#Nuevo Email
l_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=":3z"]/div/div')
l_button.click()

l_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=":1k6"]')
l_button.click()

time.sleep(1)

#Direcciones
redactar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id=":u7"]')
redactar.send_keys("marcoss@gmail ", " martin@gmail ")
```

thanks

Comment: Oh my - why aren't you just using [`smtplib`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html) and send your mails directly over GMail's SMTP servers?

Comment: i'm going to try with that but how can I add the id emails in bbc?? @LukasGraf

Comment: You didn't post the error.

Comment: I just added it @JeffC

Comment: You didn't specify which line the error is thrown. You need to take a few minutes and walk through your question and make sure it has all the info necessary to understand and reproduce the issue along with any additional information that you have relative to what else you have tried and the results there also, including any error messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to add bcc address then all you need to do control + shift + B and in selenium

```
yourElement.SendKeys(Keys.Control + Keys.Shift + "b");
```

and also your code will fail each time, bc those ids will change. So should change those xpaths as well.

IE:
'//*[@id=":3z"]/div/div' will be '//*[@id=":xp"]/div/div' next time.

so you should use:

```
#Nuevo Email
l_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//html/body/div[7]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div')
l_button.click()
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was helpful for the issue